# Is it possible to compute the start of the "current half hour" in Luxon?

Tags: momentjs, luxon

I am using Luxon and would like to compute the start of the current half hour. Currently, to get a Luxon `DateTime`, I am doing:

```
const startOfHalfHour = millis => DateTime.fromMillis(millis - (millis % (30 * 60 * 1000)))
```

Am I missing a simpler, more idiomatic way? `DateTime#startOf()` does not have a "half hour" unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luxon doesn't have a half-hour unit, so no, there's no built-in way to do that. I would do something like this:

```
DateTime.prototype.startOfHalfHour = function() {
  let result = this.startOf("hour");
  if (this.minute >= 30)
    result = result.set({ minute: 30 });
  return result;
};

var dt = DateTime
  .fromISO("2020-05-25T10:35:12")
  .startOfHalfHour();

console.log(dt.toISO());
```